# FILE pointers in Visual C++

Tags: visual-c++

I recently discovered that Visual C++ enables the building of a Form, I was always attracted by Visual Basic because of GUI but never fully learned it's language and I'm good with standard C projects, so the mix of the two is a perfect opportunity for me to start new type of projects. In my current project I have to work with the files so I have to use FILE pointers with calloc, realloc and similars. In normal situation these functions requires stdlib.h but I can't include them in the .h file of the UI due to errors in several .h files like sal.h, vadefs.h, stddef.h and others. So I tried to write my function with file operations in the .cpp but when compiling i get "identifier myFunction not found". After this i created a new .cpp file with its .h header and wrote the function there, included the header file in the .h UI file but I still got the "identifier myFunction not found" error. Can somebody help me?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I work mostly with binary/raw files with structs and use functions like fread, fwrite, rewind, fseek

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve